# ¿Cómo puedo quitar permisos de ejecución desde Java a ficheros en Windows?

Tags: java, windows, permisos

Estoy tratando de controlar los permisos de ficheros desde Java. En entornos Linux no hay ningún problema, utilizo la setExecutable() de la clase File y funciona perfectamente.

Pero en Windows setExcecutable() siempre me devuelve "false". ¿Cómo puedo quitar los permisos de ejecución en Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes, no existe ese permiso en Windows. A diferencia de Linux, un fichero es ejecutable o no dependiendo únicamente de su extensión: si ésta es `exe`, `com`, `bat`, `cmd`, `vbs` ... y otras que se pueden añadir (`jar` en caso de tener Java instalado, por ejemplo). Windows conjunta "leer y ejecutar" como un único permiso. Es decir, si puedes leer el fichero y éste tiene una extensión que lo identifica como ejecutable, será ejecutable. Por eso el API de Java no es capaz de marcar o leer ese permiso correctamente.

Por otro lado, esto es verdad desde la interfaz gráfica, desde la línea de comandos puedes ejecutar un fichero binario aunque no tenga la extensión `exe`, porque Windows lo reconocerá por ser [`MZ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) los dos primeros caracteres del mismo.

Comment: Entonces si subo un fichero desde una página web a un servidor Windows, ¿no puedo evitar que ese fichero se pueda ejecutar? Yo quería quitarle permisos de ejecución para intentar que no me puedan subir y ejecutar ficheros con código malicioso, ¿cómo puedo conseguir esto en Windows? ¿Quitando la extensión del fichero?  P.D.: Si que consigo marcar el fichero como "Read Only", pero no se si eso sirve de algo.

Comment: Puedes añadir una extensión extra al fichero, por ejemplo `malware.exe.uploaded`, pero incluso un usuario con permiso de lectura podría ejecutarlo desde la línea de comandos PowerShell

Comment: Y entonces ¿qué se hace en estos casos? ¿Cómo se protegen los servidores web Windows a los que se suben archivos desde la interfaz web?

Comment: No ejecutando esos ficheros... al fin y al cabo no se ejecutan sólos